# C++ List Processing: initializing min to first value of list

Tags: c++

The issue I am having with my code is that the min always reads 0. The reason is because I haven't properly initialized it to the first value of "random.txt". How would I do that?

Here's my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream inputFile;
    //open file
    inputFile.open("random.txt");
    int numCount = 0;
    int number, max, min, i, x;
    double average, sum;

    while(inputFile >> number)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < numCount; i++)
        {
            x = number;
            if (x < min)
            {
                min = x;
            }
            else if (x > max)
            {
                max = x;
            }
        }

        numCount++;
        sum = number + sum;
    }
    if (numCount > 0)
    {
        average = sum/numCount;
    }

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "Number of numbers is: " << numCount << endl;
    cout << "Sum of numbers is: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Average of numbers is: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Max of numbers is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "Min of numbers is: " << min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your specific concern? I would keep a `bool is_init = false` and switch it to true after u init it.

Comment: infact in your case you just want `numCount == 0`

Comment: You could also set min to the maximum value the datatype can carry -- `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` would be a good candidate.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced you will be happy with your "average" calculation, unless you intended integer-div.

Comment: The concern would be to set both max and min to the first value in "random.txt"

Comment: @WhozCraig to avoid integer division, would you suggest I use a static_cast?

Comment: You don't have to *avoid* it if it is what you want. If you want a floating point result, `static_cast<double>(sum)/numCount;` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `min` to the largest possible value, and `max` to the lowest possible value.

Like

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

See [here for a reference of `std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

---

As hinted to by WhozCraig in a comment to this answer, your `if-else if` construct is not the best if the numbers in the file are just getting lower, and no values are bigger than the previous value.

You might want to do either what WhozCraig suggests in the comment, or change to two separate `if` statements.

---

**Sample**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("random.txt");
    int number, max=0, min=0;
    int numCount = 0;
    double average=0, sum=0;

    if (inputFile >> number)
    {
        min = max = number;
        numCount = 1;
        while(inputFile >> number)
        {
            if (number < min)
                min = number;
            else if (number > max)
                max = number;

            sum += number;
            ++numCount;
        }

        average = static_cast<double>(sum)/numCount;
    }

    cout << "Number of numbers is: " << numCount << endl;
    cout << "Sum of numbers is: " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Average of numbers is: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Max of numbers is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "Min of numbers is: " << min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He should read the first number, set `min = max = number`, then enter the loop with `numCount` set to one. Doing what you're describing with his current if-then-else-if logic will have an interesting and unintended side-effect if the list contains either a single value or any strictly descending sequence. `max` will never be cleared of the initial `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` value.

Comment: Actually, I was incorrect, but only because that for-loop that appears to be doing nothing will actually "fix" this, but I'm not sure that was the intention. =P Without it, this is definitely a problem. With it, it self-corrects, but creates an O(N^2) comparison-read sequence. You can do this with the same if-else-if construct, so long as the initial value of max and min are one of the values in the sequence (i.e. the first one), and throw out the for-loop in the process.

Comment: @WhozCraig that makes sense. But when I do this: for (i = 0; i < numCount; i++)
  {
            number = max = min;
   x = number;
   if (x < min)
   {
    min = x;
   }
            else if (x > max)
   {
    max = x;
   }
        }
        
Both the min and max become 0.

Comment: @JohnDAngelo I threw a sample in Joachim's answer. Wrote it on the fly so sorry about typos. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @WhozCraig: THANK YOU! Just one question, what is the purpose of the if statement being first? "if(inputFile>>number)" and how is that different from "while(inputFile>>number)"

Comment: @JohnDAngelo I'll answer that with a question: What happens to this thing if the file is *empty* on inception?

Comment: Ahh! We are IF(INPUT>>NUMBER) tests whether the file is empty whereas WHILE(INPUT>>NUMBER) reads the data! Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers are int, try to init min to INT_MAX and max to INT_MIN. You can find these macros in limits.h.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Answer (score 0):

Initialize min to the maximum integer value possible:

1. Include the `<climits>` header file (See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) for details)
2. Initialize `min = INT_MAX`.

This will work great, but won't work as expected in case there are no numbers at all in the file. To work around that, you should use a boolean variable (initialized to `false`), and set it to `true` inside your `while` loop. Thus, after the loop exits, you will be able to tell whether the values of `min` and `max` are real, or just the initial values that haven't been changed (another way to do that would be to test, after the loop, whether `min` is bigger than `max` - if it is, then the file was empty).

Also notice that it seems that the `for` loop is redundant, and doesn't even execute for the first number.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream inputFile;
//open file
inputFile.open("random.txt");
int numCount = 0;
int number = 0, max = 0, min = 0, i = 0;
double average = 0, sum = 0;
bool first = true;
while (inputFile >> number)
{
    if (first){
        first = false;
        max = min = number;
    }
    if (number < min)
    {
        min = number;
    }
    else if (number > max)
    {
        max = number;
    }
    numCount++;
    sum = number + sum;
}
```

This is I edit. I hope you can get your answer.